# Workflows in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-4, workflow

As we all know Joomla 4 is on the horizon and the improvement to workflows are definitely an interesting addition.

From what I've seen, the workflow works great for new content, but what about content that's already live that needs to be edited? Could this be used in conjunction with the article version control which set's an edited article to the beginning of the workflow whilst the live version remains live until the edits are approved?

Anyone had any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

The Joomla 4 workflow allows you to replace the static states (unpublished, published, trashed and archived) with your own custom solution. When you assign a workflow to a category of articles, this would apply both to new and existing content. That said, you may have issues if the state of the existing article does not exist in the new workflow applied to that category, and presumably this is where the default state would apply when you next edit it.

What you are suggesting with regards to article versions is an interesting idea, but it seems to be more of a feature request rather than something that is currently possible with an out of the box Joomla 4 install. It does seem like an idea that could be pursued by a third party extension developer.

Comment: Welcome to the community Tim, please take our [tour] and introduce yourself by editing your profile -- this is a good place to park any links to your presentations/books.  Finally, I can update this page: https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/385/12352